# Responsive Image in responsive Div or table

Tags: jquery, css, image, html, responsive-design

I want to make my website responsive. When accessing the site with your smartphone, our logo should be at the top and should have the entire width of the phone screen. 
I tried this:

```
.image {
      background-image: url("imageurl.jpg");
     background-size: contain;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     max-width:100pc;
     max-height:auto;
}
```

The problem is, that you need to define a size for the div or td were the image is in. I don't know the size, because the size of the screens will vary. Do I need a div or td, that is responsive and changes its size?

Any ideas?

Comment: you can try setting the width to `100%`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For responsive image in table [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/yZ4va/24/)

```
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 100% 
}

td { 
    border: 1px solid #000; 
}

img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

For responsive image in div [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7uhBb/)

```
.image{
  width:100%;
  height:20em; // your height 100%, or fixed
  display:block;
  background:url('yourpath/image.jpg')no-repeat center center;nd-size:cover; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! 
This is a very good start! td is now resizing horizontal! There is still one problem though: I want the logo always to be seen entirely. It should resize vertically automatically. Keep in mind, that I want everyone to see the entire logo, regardless which screen-size the mobile device has.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a background image. Use an `<img>` tag. Set `max-width: 100%;` on your `img` element.

Comment: Also @Misa
I use this approach usually, this time it did not work though. I want the div or table to be resized depending on the screen, like Gaurav did it. Together with Gadgetster way it works almost fine. Img and Div get resized, BUT I do not see the entire img! Only its length. What do I have to do, that the img is completely seen in its height, too?

Answer (score 0):

Set `width` (not `max-width`) to `100%` and use `height:auto` in order to scale with different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.image {
     background: url(images.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I combined your approach with Gauravs. Good start, but still one thing that does not work: The automatic resize of the height! I want the image to be seen entirely, regardless how wide it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
.images{
       background-size:100% auto;   
       //here 100% is for width and auto is height(for self adjusting according to width )
       max-width:A px;   //where A is the actual width of image 
}
```

Comment: I use this usually. Pls look at the comment of Andrei, who suggested about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the quick answers. I combined two suggested approaches, as shown in the code.
The Table and the img resize now, depending on the size of the screen.

There is still one problem though: The img is shown in it's entire length's, but not in it's height! 
I would like the img always to be seen entirely.

```
    <style>
table { 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 100% 
}

td { 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-image:url("http://www.s4ea.org/images/logor.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
     background-size: cover;
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;

}




</style>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>image</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!